# IIS Hosted Workflow Service How to Detect Application Start and Stop

Tags: iis-7, workflow-foundation-4

I want to hook into the application start and stop events to track whether my IIS Hosted Workflow Services are running. Ideally, when I start my workflow service via starting the AppPool or the IIS Application (if multiple services share the same AppPool), I want to log an event into a database. And when I stop my workflow service via stopping the AppPool or the IIS Application, I want to log an event into the database.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you want to intercept that the app is started/stopped by the administration console, not just that the app is simply started, correct?

Comment: apps hosted on iis have start and stop event in global.asax, iis will even tell you (in event args) why it is shutting down your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this article on Windows Server AppFabric.  Specifically, take a look at the section on "Tracked WF Events".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677205(v=azure.10).aspx

AppFabric is a separate install (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637745(v=azure.10).aspx), but I think it will go a long way towards helping you accomplish your objectives regarding workflow and service monitoring.

[Install AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637745%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that Application_Start & Application_End are executed too early (or too late) during the application life-cycle and I assume that things like DataBase Access object will not be available for you use.

My recommendation is to use FileSystem to exchange the data.

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\something\hello.txt", FileMode.Append);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        sw.Flush();
        fs.Close();

    }
```

This will write anything you want into a text file, which you can then read with a simple service and fetch the relevant data.